# How do you select a directory or a list of filenames with PyQt4 and pass it to a variable in python

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am an absolute beginner with PyQt but I have fairly conversant with Python and Pygame. I am writing a file utility for Windows and I need to get either a directory path or paths of several selected files into a variable or a list. How is this possible using pyqt? I know how to do it with tk but I have compiling errors using tk. Please try to give me a direct answer to this question instead of finding fault with my approach to this matter. My code which I tried with pyqt is given below.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Qtthings(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Qtthings, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        self.resize(350, 450)  # screen size xy
        self.center()
        self.setWindowTitle('Select Directory')
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('dg64.ico'))
        self.fileDialog = QtGui.QFileDialog(self)
        self.fileDialog.show()




    def center(self):

        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()  # get the screen center
        qr.moveCenter(cp)  # this where the frameshould move
        self.move(qr.topLeft())  # move the top left in relation to the center

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Qtthings()
    #a = ex.fileDialog
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fp = main()
    print fp
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the shortest way to do this was

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    a = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames()
    if a:
        for name in a:
            print name
```

Comment: Didn't know there was a getOpenFileName**s** method...we learn everyday!